# Remove the prefix 'Default' from API documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

There is some way to remove the prefix 'Default.' from the API endpoints on Swagger documentation? We actualy don't use this prefixes to accesss our endpoints so we don't need that in there.

[PrintScreen from Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o2mr.png)

Comment: Do you have some swagger customization?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk No, only these filters: `c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
                    c.OperationFilter<DescriptionOperationFilter>();
                    c.OperationFilter<OAuth2SwashBuckleOperationFilter>();`

Comment: We need to see the code that represents the action from screen

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Controller: `[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddListCargos(ODataActionParameters cargos)`   ApiConfig: `builder.EntityType<CargoApiDTO>().Collection.Action("AddListCargos").Returns<string>().CollectionEntityParameter<CargoApiDTO>("cargos");`

Comment: In your comment: `AddListCargos` but on screen `AddListSetores`

Comment: @RomanMarusyk My mistake. But it is the same for `AddListSetores`